# How to use GeoServer securely in production with Tomcat Policies?

Tags: geoserver, installation, tomcat

I want to use GeoServer (first testing, then production) but we have to use Tomcat policies for security reasons.

I have already tried to deploy GeoServer with the security manager enabled, but GeoServer will only work if granting explicit access to the root (/) of the server.

Is this so? I didn't find anything in the docs.

Does anyone know how to get GeoServer working with Tomcat policies?